# SPContext.Current throws SecurityException for most properties

Tags: sharepoint, exception

Many properties for SPContext.Current objects throws SecurityException. (Like SPContext.Current.Fields, many properties in SPContext.Current.Site (see details).

- DLL Is in GAC
- Using Site Owner when trying those
  properties.
- Maybe it has to do something with
  database access? However SharePoint
  site is working - I can add list
  items, etc.
- Application Pool has permissions to
  database. Should I set application
  pool account as farm admin or it is
  not necessary?
- **In my Development environment, it
  just works.**

Where could be the problem? Could someone, please, point me in right direction?

Thank you.

## Details

From Immediate window:

```
SPContext.Current.Site
{Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite}
    AllowRssFeeds: true
    AllowUnsafeUpdates: 'SPContext.Current.Site.AllowUnsafeUpdates' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException'
    AllWebs: {Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection}
    ApplicationRightsMask: 9223372036854775807
    Audit: {Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAudit}
    CatchAccessDeniedException: true
    CertificationDate: 'SPContext.Current.Site.CertificationDate' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException'
    ContentDatabase: {Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase}
    CurrentChangeToken: 'SPContext.Current.Site.CurrentChangeToken' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException'
    ...
```

And even exception have exception's within himself:

[Exception Window http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/442/ss20100204112542.png](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/442/ss20100204112542.png)

ULS Log somwhere in that time, when exception occurs:
[ULS Log http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/465/ss20100204113046.png](http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/465/ss20100204113046.png)

Event Viewer has bunch of errors

- for SharePoint search Indexer (i
  don't have a working search at the
  moment, I just hope it is not the
  problem)
- And there is an error about Alternate
  Access Mapping (Sometimes I access
  SharePoint from IP address, not from
  hostname, as hostnames do not resolve
  in VPN for me, but that's a different
  problem):

  The description for Event ID ( 8214 ) in Source ( Windows SharePoint Services 3 )  cannot be found. The
     local computer may not have the
     necessary registry information or
     message DLL files to display messages
     from a remote computer. You may be
     able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to
     retrieve this description; see Help
     and Support for details. The
     following information is part of the
     event: A request was made for a URL,
     http://192.168.0.9, which has not
     been configured in Alternate Access
     Mappings.  Some links may point to
     the Alternate Access URL for the
     default zone, http://serveris. 
     Review the Alternate Access mappings
     for this Web application at
     http://serveris:38590/_admin/AlternateUrlCollections.aspx
     and consider adding
     http://192.168.0.9 as a Public
     Alternate Access URL if it will be
     used frequently.  Help on this error:
     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, the issue is now resolved after stepping already like 3rd time on the same rake.

It was happening in WebPart constructor (do not know if it plays a role, but inherited from `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart`) and there the SPContext object was messed up.

Interesting that it works in my development environment.

Answer (score 1):

I know I have had to use code to ensure that the SPContext exists when executing from a non-web context.

```
public static void EnsureSPContext(this SPWeb web)
    {
        // Ensure HttpContext.Current
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest("", web.Url, "");
            HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(request,
              new HttpResponse(TextWriter.Null));
        }

        // SPContext is based on SPControl.GetContextWeb(), which looks here
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] == null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = web;

    }
```